# Converting GLib.Array to built in array

Tags: glib, vala

Lets say I have a `GLib.Array<Item?>` and want to convert that into a `Item[]`, how would I do that in Vala?

Answer (score 5):

First off, unless you need to for interoperability with existing code, don't use `GLib.Array`.  Use [`GLib.GenericArray`](http://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.GenericArray.html), which is much easier to use correctly and harder to use incorrectly.

`GLib.Array.data` is a regular array (`Item?[]` in your case), as is `GLib.GenericArray.data`, so you can just use that.  If you assign it to an owned variable Vala will make a copy.

Answer (score 2):

A naive approach would be, that you take out all the items from the array with the `index()` method and append them to an empty `Item[]` array, using `+=`.

A simple example program:

```cs
public int main (string[] args) {
    Array<string> array = new Array<string> ();
    array.append_val ("1. entry");
    array.append_val ("2. entry");

    string[] builtin = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        builtin += array.index (i);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**update:** `GLib.GenericArray` really seems like a better solution. As for the `data` attribute: At `GenericArray` it is documented at [Valadoc](http://www.valadoc.org/#!api=glib-2.0/GLib.GenericArray), at `Array` it isn't (that doesn't mean it does not work, but I haven't tried it).

Comment: GLib.Array.data is pretty new (currently only available in the development version, which will become 0.26), but it works.